# istio request validation succed only after few times of retrial

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

when I send api request to my service that has istio sidecar running on its side with `RequestAuthentication` enabled I get a 401 response that says:

```
Jwks doesn't have key to match kid or alg from Jwt
```

After re-sending the same request a few times, I get a desired response from the service. I am not exactly sure where the problem is but I am thinking it might be something with istio caching something?